# How to get $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\left \|a + t\frac{a}{\|a\|} \right\| - \|a\|}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(\|a\|+t) - \|a\|}{t}$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

I'm watching Professor Shifrin's lectures [here](https://youtu.be/VG3J1MdhebA?t=435), at which he mentioned:

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\left \|a  + t\dfrac{a}{\|a\|} \right\|  - \|a\|}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{(\|a\|+t)  - \|a\|}{t}$$

In my computation, $\left \|a  + t\dfrac{a}{\|a\|} \right\| = \|a\| \cdot |1+t/\|a\||$. I could not simplify more. Could you please elaborate on how to get the result?

Comment: The expression under lim, on the right of =, is clearly 1, hence this limit is 1. The expression under lim, on the left, is −1 for negative , and 1, for the positive . If we restrict  to positive  then we get the equality of the left limit and the right limit. But even for arbitrary $t$ but small, meaning that $|t|\le ||a||$ we still get equality, hence the two limits are always equal. (I messed up at one moment, and @MadnessForMath straightened me up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no super tricky calculation involved, actually; all you need is to add the fraction and the $1$ to see what's happening:

$$ \left \|a  + t\dfrac{a}{\|a\|} \right\| = \|a\| \cdot \left|1+ \frac{t}{\|a\|} \right|
= \|a\| \cdot \left|\frac{\|a\| + t}{\|a\|} \right| = \left|\|a\| + t \right| = \|a\| + t . $$

Then, what you wanted becomes clear!

Comment: You have $\left|\|a\| + t \right| = \|a\| + t$ because $\|a\| + t \ge 0$ when $t \to 0$ right?

Comment: @MadnessForMATH, only if $t\ge 0$. If $t<0$ then this is false.

Comment: Hi @WlodAA, When $t \to 0$, $\|t\| \le \|a\|$ and thus $\|a\| + t \ge 0$.

Comment: @MadnessForMATH, you're right. I missed $t\rightarrow 0$ for a moment.